# Headless Chrome script to use the same session and skip two-factor authentication

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless, two-factor-authentication

There is a website that uses two-factor authentication. On the login form there is a checkbox that, when checked, allows me to bypass the two-factor authentication step (for the current device) in the future after successfully logging in the first time. I was hoping to do this manually at first, and then use headless Chrome to automate logging in. I thought that by pointing puppeteer to my Chrome application and also pointing the `userDataDir` to my profile, it would allow puppeteer to access the site already logged in. But when I access the site with puppeteer, it still shows the two-factor authentication step.

Does anyone know what might be missing that would allow me to access the site without two-factor authentication? Just to clarify: Using Chrome manually and logging in does not display the two-factor authentication step, but using puppeteer does.

Note in the following code, `#remember-me` is the checkbox that allows me to skip the two-factor auth.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome', 
        headless: true, 
        userDataDir: '/Users/xxxx/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome'
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://portal.insperity.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        document.querySelector('#username').value = 'username';
        document.querySelector('#password').value = 'password';
        document.querySelector('#remember-me').checked = true;
        document.querySelector('#submit').click();
    })
    await page.waitFor(1000);
    await page.screenshot({path: 'page2.png'});
    await browser.close();
})();
```

**Update:** I tried changing the `headless` property to `false` and commenting out the `await browser.close()` line and executing the script. In the Chrome instance that launched, I noticed that I am not signed into Google or Stack Overflow. So it looks like my cookies are not being sent. What could be causing this or what am I missing?

For reference, here are specs of the software I am using:

- MacOS 10.13.2
- Chrome 65.0.3325.181
- Puppeteer 1.3.0
- Node 10.0.0

Comment: From what I see, this is a bug in chrome where custom data dir doesn't work.

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher I checked the Chrome instance that launched and it does show my profile name in the top right of the Chrome window. When I don't pass in `userDataDir`, it just shows something like "anonymous" (I forgot exactly what it said).

Comment: We are discussing this problem in this issue https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1316

Answer (score 1):

if your web site uses cookies for authentication, you might be better of setting cookies and bypass  two-factor authentication. but that means you would have to get the cookies from somewhere.

```
await page.goto('https://youhomepage.com');

    let cookieObject ={
        name:"JSESSIONID",
        value:"9C8E6659B14C2963EDED73C16BB0868A",
        Expires:"Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT"
        }

await page.setCookie(cookieObject);
await page.waitFor(1000);
await page.goto('https://youhomepage.com');
```